How do I fill up a PCI DSS SAQ form?
I have established that my business needs to complete a PCI DSS SAQ-D form for attesting PCI compliance... twice - once as a merchant and once as a service provider!
Even completing it once is a substantial undertaking, considering the size of the documents in question (over 100 pages each).
These documents are provided as PDFs. Seemingly I need to print these out and complete them by hand (and then likely scan them back into digital form for storage and delivery to requesting entities), begging the question of which century I am presently in.
Can anybody who has been through this process provide practical advice on how best to complete this document in digital form so that:

I can save the planet and my budget by minimising wasted paper and printer ink
Save the work as I proceed and allow the burden to be more easily shared with colleagues
Allow me to revisit the form in future years and adjust answers as needed, rather than having to start from scratch (and cut down another tree in the process)

Will purchasing a copy of Adobe Acrobat make my life any easier in this respect? That is, do the documents in question actually contain form elements that Acrobat would enable me to fill in and check boxes for?
On a final note, I know this is not a technical question regarding information security per se, but it seems to fall between stools as far as SE site topics go.

"How do I fill out a PDF?" is not a security question, regardless of the content of the PDF.

If you're on windows, Edge actually has a very robust set of annotation tools. I distinctly recall you can reedit after saving but you probably already have it so can't beat the cost.

The Forms certainly version 4.0 do NOT have "prepared data fields" for data import and export in bulk. IF they did they would all "normally" appear with a blue field
However as pointed out by @gowenfawr Acrobat Reader (Editor ) DC can provide form recognition where it "optically" recognises boxes and underlines as potential form candidates.


These are not usable fields simply edited "paths" and thus non repeatable in other copies.


In order to build true DATA field you would need a fuller editor Such as Tracker etc.

If you dont want to install a large suite of software there are online form generators including Adobe Online (same as Reader NOT fields) but Acrobat PRO could perhaps do it semi-automatically?, I suggest use a trial copy first. See https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/resources/how-to-create-fillable-pdf.html

Simple Answer
As suggested by @JourneymanGeek MS Edge is "FREE" on Windows and can do very similar basic task with editable annotations. It should be good for multiple users but do keep "Work In Progress" copies since sometimes a save may "flatten" the notes into the body then its harder to adjust.


I have since discovered (indirectly by working with Stripe) that the SAQ forms can also be downloaded as DOCX files, which makes the form filling process much more practical. Go to the page below, then select SAQ in the Filter by field. You will be able to pick PDF or DOCX versions of the SAQ form that you need:
https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/document_library/
